# Android drag and drop on dynamically created views

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

could really do with some help.

I have a random number of buttons being created on the fly and each button is setOnTouchListener, which looks to be working fine. The buttons are added to Linearlayout (Top) and there is another empty Linearlayout (Bottom).

I want to be able to do the following:

1. Drag & Drop buttons between Linearlayout (Top) & Linearlayout (Bottom)

   ```
    public class GetString extends Activity{

    myDragEventListener mDragListen = new myDragEventListener();

     public void getString(Context context, String[] temp, int no,  LinearLayout words1, LinearLayout words2) {


      Button bt;

      int i = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < no; i++) {

        bt = new Button(context);
        bt.setId(i);
        bt.setText(temp[i]);
        bt.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        words1.addView(bt);
        bt.setOnDragListener(mDragListen);
      }
     }


   protected class myDragEventListener implements View.OnDragListener {


    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

       // Defines a variable to store the action type for the incoming event
       final int action = event.getAction();

       // Handles each of the expected events
       switch(action) {

           case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

               return false;

           case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

               v.invalidate();

               return true;

           case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:

               return true;

           case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

               v.invalidate();

               return true;

           case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

               return true;

           case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:



               return true;

           // An unknown action type was received.
           default:
               Log.e("DragDrop Example", "Unknown action type received by OnDragListener.");
               break;
       }

       return false;
     }
    }


   public class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
       ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
       View.DragShadowBuilder shadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
       v.startDrag(data, shadow, null, 0);
       return false;
     }
   }


   }
   ```

Comment: i also have this problem. what did you do?